# Who is this Taiwanese diplomat/politician standing next to Tsai Ing-wen (蔡英文), president of the Republic of China (Taiwan)

Tags: international-relations, taiwan

Please take a look at this [full resolution image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c1/President_Tsai_poses_for_a_photo_with_a_delegation_led_by_Solomon_Islands_Prime_Minister_Manasseh_Sogavare_%2826_September_2017%29_in_Taipei%2C_Taiwan.jpg) (for more information, see [its archive page](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:President_Tsai_poses_for_a_photo_with_a_delegation_led_by_Solomon_Islands_Prime_Minister_Manasseh_Sogavare_(26_September_2017)_in_Taipei,_Taiwan.jpg)) of a Taiwanese and Solomon Islands politicians and diplomats posing for a photo with a delegation led by Solomon Islands Prime Minister Manasseh Sogavare (26 September 2017) in Taipei, Taiwan.

In **the bottom row** one can identify the Prime Minister of Solomon Islands, Manasseh Sogavare (**second person from the left**), and the President of the Republic of China (Taiwan), Tsai Ing-wen (蔡英文) (**third person from the left**).

I am wondering if anybody could tell me the name of the **fourth person from the left**, i.e. the person standing on the right side of President Tsai.

One can note that, during other state visits (again in relation to the Solomon Islands), the same person also takes seat next to President Tsai:

- [Picture 1](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:11.02_%E7%B8%BD%E7%B5%B1%E8%88%87%E9%9A%A8%E5%9C%98%E8%A8%98%E8%80%85%E8%8C%B6%E6%95%98%EF%BC%8C%E6%8C%87%E5%87%BA%EF%BC%8C%E6%AD%A4%E6%AC%A1%E5%87%BA%E8%A8%AA%EF%BC%8C%E6%88%91%E5%80%91%E7%89%B9%E5%88%A5%E9%97%9C%E6%B3%A8%E6%95%99%E8%82%B2%E3%80%81%E9%86%AB%E7%99%82%E5%92%8C%E8%BE%B2%E6%A5%AD%E7%AD%89%E4%B8%89%E9%A0%85%E9%A0%98%E5%9F%9F%E7%9A%84%E5%90%88%E4%BD%9C%E9%A0%85%E7%9B%AE%E3%80%82%E4%BA%8B%E5%AF%A6%E4%B8%8A%EF%BC%8C%E9%80%99%E4%B8%89%E5%80%8B%E9%A0%85%E7%9B%AE%E5%85%B7%E9%AB%94%E5%B1%95%E7%8F%BE%E8%87%BA%E7%81%A3%E7%9A%84%E5%B0%88%E6%A5%AD%E8%83%BD%E5%8A%9B%EF%BC%8C%E4%BB%A5%E5%8F%8A%E8%83%BD%E7%82%BA%E5%9C%8B%E9%9A%9B%E7%A4%BE%E6%9C%83%E6%89%80%E5%B8%B6%E4%BE%86%E7%9A%84.jpg)
- [Picture 2](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:11.02_%E7%B8%BD%E7%B5%B1%E8%88%87%E9%9A%A8%E5%9C%98%E8%A8%98%E8%80%85%E8%8C%B6%E6%95%98%EF%BC%8C%E6%8F%90%E5%88%B0%E9%80%99%E5%B9%BE%E6%97%A5%E6%AF%8F%E5%A4%A9%E7%9D%9C%E9%96%8B%E7%9C%BC%E7%9D%9B%EF%BC%8C%E7%9C%8B%E5%88%B0%E7%9A%84%E9%83%BD%E6%98%AF%E8%97%8D%E8%89%B2%E6%B5%B7%E6%B4%8B%E3%80%82%E7%9B%B8%E4%BF%A1%E5%9C%A8%E5%9C%8B%E9%9A%9B%E5%90%88%E4%BD%9C%E9%A0%98%E5%9F%9F%EF%BC%8C%E8%87%BA%E7%81%A3%E7%9A%84%E8%83%BD%E5%8A%9B%E5%92%8C%E8%87%AA%E4%BF%A1%EF%BC%8C%E4%B9%9F%E5%8F%AF%E4%BB%A5%E5%89%B5%E9%80%A0%E5%B1%AC%E6%96%BC%E6%88%91%E5%80%91%E5%9C%A8%E5%9C%8B%E9%9A%9B%E7%A4%BE%E6%9C%83%E7%9A%84%E3%80%8C%E8%97%8D%E6%B5%B7%E3%80%8D_(38054398656).jpg)
- [Picture 3](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:11.02_%E7%B8%BD%E7%B5%B1%E8%88%87%E9%9A%A8%E5%9C%98%E8%A8%98%E8%80%85%E8%8C%B6%E6%95%98%EF%BC%8C%E8%AA%AA%E6%98%8E%E6%AD%A4%E8%A1%8C%E6%88%90%E6%9E%9C%EF%BC%8C%E4%B9%9F%E5%9B%9E%E6%87%89%E9%9A%A8%E5%9C%98%E8%A8%98%E8%80%85%E6%8F%90%E5%95%8F_(38108043181).jpg)

I have also asked for help in the comment sections (towards the bottom, visible after a long lag) of these Chinese language webpages:

https://www.ettoday.net/news/20171102/1043982.htm
https://www.ettoday.net/news/20171102/1043962.htm
https://www.ettoday.net/news/20171102/1043961.htm
https://www.ettoday.net/news/20171102/1043929.htm

Comment: I can identify the man standing behind the president as Ambassador Roger Luo.

Comment: @JamesK Yes, I had already identified him. He is mentioned and tagged on [the picture's archival page](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:President_Tsai_poses_for_a_photo_with_a_delegation_led_by_Solomon_Islands_Prime_Minister_Manasseh_Sogavare_(26_September_2017)_in_Taipei,_Taiwan.jpg).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's **Office of the President Secretary-General [Joseph Wu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Wu)** (**[吳釗燮](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%90%B3%E9%87%97%E7%87%AE)**).

Other persons deemed to have been recognized, so far, are:

- George Herming;
- Joseph Waleanisia;
- Nestor Ghiro;
- Jackson Fiulaua;
- Rosie;
- Mrs Luo;
- John Dean Kuku;
- Bartholomew Parapolo;
- Roger Tian-hung Luo;
- John Maneniaru;
- Icyang Parod;
- Emmy Sogavare;
- Manasseh Sogavare;
- Tsai Ing-wen;
- David Lee Ta-wei;
- Chin Lin.